# Applying the reverse triangle inequality to a product of differences.

Tags: complex-analysis

This is something that came up in a similar problem with complex numbers, I just want to make sure it's mathematically legal to apply the reverse-triangle inequality to a product of two differences like this:

$|(a-b)(c-d)| \geq (|a|-|b|)(|c|-|d|)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is correct because you can insert some extra steps:
$$|(a-b)(c-d)|=|a-b||c-d|\ge\bigl||a|-|b|\bigr|.\bigl||c|-|d|\bigr|\ .$$
Now if $|a|-|b|$ and $|c|-|d|$ are both positive, or both negative, then you have your inequality.  If one is positive and one is negative then your inequality says $|(a-b)(c-d)|$ is greater than or equal to a negative number, which is trivially true.